# How to import categories in an easy way?

Tags: integration, pentaho, etl, kettle

I have made a transformation to import some categories with kettle. This categories have 4 columns: parent; son1; son2; son3.

This was a little bit more complicated from what i was expecting for, so my question is: There aren't a easiest way to do it?

Below there's an image with my transformation.
[Click here to see my transformation!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl7zP.jpg)
Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: question is not clear enough.. can u explain a bit more !!!